# Converting an English Statement into a Questi0n

Tags: algorithm, nlp, artificial-intelligence

(Apologies for the title. Stack overflow doesn't allow the word "Question" in titles.)

How would one go about writing an algorithm to convert an english statement into a question? Where would one even begin? For example:

"*The ingredients for an omelette are eggs, bacon, cheese, and onions*" would become "*What are the ingredients for an omelette?*" or "*The ingredients for an omelette are what?*"

I can imagine parsing a sentence into it's components, and then re-arranging these while adding and removing words to form a grammatically correct sentence, but I'd have no idea where to start. I know this is by no means a trivial task, and I think the most helpful thing right now would be pointers to literature or similar problems.

Comment: Could have written "converting English imperative statements to interrogative."

Comment: @DonReba gotta fight the power, man.

Comment: seems like a Watson Jeopardy project, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer)#Competing_on_Jeopardy.21

Comment: @DonReba then I wouldn't have landed on this from google (I've never used imperative and interrogative words in my search query)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [ACL Anthology](http://aclweb.org/anthology/) for the papers published on Question Generation using template-based approaches.

Below are a few to start:

Popowich, David Lindberg Fred, and John Nesbit Phil Winne. "Generating Natural Language Questions to Support Learning On-Line."
https://aclweb.org/anthology/W/W13/W13-2114.pdf

Rokhlenko, Oleg, and Idan Szpektor. "Generating Synthetic Comparable Questions for News Articles."
http://aclweb.org/anthology/P/P13/P13-1073.pdf

Zhao, Shiqi, et al. "Automatically Generating Questions from Queries for Community-based Question Answering." IJCNLP. 2011.
https://aclweb.org/anthology/I/I11/I11-1104.pdf

Comment: I asked this question 5 years ago as an undergrad. 5 years later and I'm using that second paper you referenced as a citation for work in grad school. That's pretty  cool.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you don't want to start from scratch take a look at  Stanford's lex parser.
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml
It's a pretty great tool.

I would parse the text and find out the grammatical structure of a sentence. Once that's done you just have to find a question for a specific part of speech.

You can also read tons of publications at http://nlp.stanford.edu/publications.shtml 
Good luck searching.

Answer (score -2):

That is an interesting question. Just from the top of my head: you would need to construct a DB that will hold words categorized by what they are, for example prepositions, "linking words"(or whatever they are called, and others...

Arrange the words of the sentence in an array(list) and cycle through each one. When a certain word appears that is in a certain category do something.

For example:
"The" might tell you that the next word is the subject.

"ingredients" is the subject but has an "s" so expect multiple somethings,
look for the next word that symbolizes (linking) like "are"

"of" tells you that the next word is the subject of which the above link to,

"are"  tells you that a list of something is next, store them in a separate table but linking them to subjects.

preposition words and statement = take them out as they are not needed.

Once you have everything separated out into different lists then just construct your simple question. If you know the answer has multiple answers start with "What are" then add the subject of the elements.

Something basic like that. But I am more than certain that you are going to have to figure out what each word means in the sentence so you can find out how to categorize them and store them some how to then ask a question for it.

Hope that points you (in a) direction.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is negatively flagged, at the very least it is an attempt to solve the problem, even though it might not be the best solution out there - an attempt is still an attempt and not to be discouraged over.